# Embded a delete in select statement in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I am trying to embed a Delete operation in SELECT in postgres. Tried the following command but its not working.. :(

```
select * from tasks where title ilike '% 
Delete from tasks where title ilike `%Re%` returning ( 
Select title from tasks where title ilike `%smoke%`)%'
```

where the actual query in TS looks like

```
select * from tasks where title ilike '%${filter}%'
```

I'm trying to fit the

```
Delete from tasks where title ilike '%Re%' returning ( 
Select title from tasks where title ilike '%smoke%')
```

in the place of '%{filter}%'

I am getting errors all around and not able to perform the operation!

Comment: The `returning` clause as written does not make sense. It does not accept a sub-query. You can only specify a list of columns to be returned. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I'm trying to do SQL injection testing on the form which I have built using Nest.js. This form queries the backend using select * from tasks where title like '%${filter}%'. Here the filter is the query param sent from front end

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute an invalid `SQL` statement. If you want to return rows from the delete statement you can use the `CTE`:

```
WITH del AS (
   -- it will be better to get the task id here
   DELETE FROM tasks WHERE title ILIKE '%Re%' RETURNING title
)
   SELECT title FROM del WHERE title ILIKE '%smoke%'
```

Comment: Yea, I wanted to use the SQL injection to test the form, I wanted to make it secure as it would have a direct impact on the table performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function and lateral achieve that.

```
CREATE temp TABLE tasks (
    title text
    , misc numeric DEFAULT random() ::numeric
);
INSERT INTO tasks (title)
    VALUES ('foo bar');
INSERT INTO tasks (title)
    VALUES ('Re')
    , ('Re_1')
    , ('smoke_1')
    , ('smoke_2')
    , ('smoke_3')
    , ('foo bar')
    , ('brown');'
```

simple function, use case insensitive regex pattern match to delete rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_tasks_title_pattern (x text)
    RETURNS void
    AS $func$
    DELETE FROM tasks
    WHERE title ~* x;
$func$
LANGUAGE sql
STRICT;
```

Then the following query will do select (title ILIKE '%smoke%') and delete (title ~* 'foo')

```
SELECT
    sub.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        tasks
    WHERE
        title ILIKE '%smoke%') sub
    , LATERAL delete_tasks_title_pattern ('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to exploit SQL injection by replacing `'%${filter}%'` with some sub-query that deletes rows.

You can't have a sub-query that runs a DML statement, but you can use the well known [little bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) approach to inject a DELETE statement.

Assuming that `${filter}` will be replaced at runtime with the value provided, and you pass the following string as the filter parameter:

```
';delete from tasks where true or title = '
```

then the query is turned into two queries:

```
select * from tasks where title ilike '%';
delete from tasks where true or title = '%'
```